# Heroku - Enable / Disable Weekly Backups

Tags: heroku, database-backups

I'm using the free heroku add-on PG Backups and followed these [instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#creating-a-backup). I found the command to install the app: heroku addons:add pgbackups:auto-week. However I m wondering how I can enable / disable the weekly backups.

```
heroku addons:add pgbackups:auto-week
Adding pgbackups:auto-week on myProject... failed
 !    pgbackups:plus add-on already added.
 !    To upgrade, use addons:upgrade instead.
```

Comment: No answer yet ;-) Will update you as soon as I get an answer.. I submitted a ticket to heroku including the link to this question, thus they might add an additional answer here.

Comment: Answer from support was: Automatic backups are available for dev and basic database plans, but a verified account is needed. For a verified account you need to provide your creditcart credentials. Whereas since the addon is free, you will not be charged.

Comment: Excellent! Did that work for you then? If so feel free to post it as an answer, unaccept my answer, and accept your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Postgres Dev Center article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#backups) mentions that automatic backups are only enabled for production databases (i.e. [Crane tier database payment plans and higher](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql)). Perhaps the PG Backups add-on doesn't perform automatic backups on 'Starter' tier (i.e. 'dev' or 'basic') database plans?

It might be worth checking with Heroku Support to see if this is the case and if the [PG Backups article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups) needs to be updated.